# Use Class property value for a switch statement

Tags: c#

am using generated protobuf code (see http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

I have a generated class looks like this :

```
public class Fruits{
    private int _ID_BANANA = (int)1;
    private int _ID_APPLE  = (int)2;

    public int ID_BANANA
    {
      get { return _ID_BANANA; }
      set { _ID_BANANA = value; }
    }

    public int ID_APPLE
    {
      get { return _ID_APPLE; }
      set { _ID_APPLE = value; }
    }
}
```

Then they are constant values but I can't use then as such in my code.
For example I want to do a mapper like this :

```
public static Color GetColor(int idFruit) {    
    switch (idFruit)
        {
            case new Fruits().ID_BANANA:
                return Color.Yellow;
            case new Fruits().ID_APPLE:
                return Color.Green; 
            default:
                return Color.White;                 
        }
 }
```

I have the error : a constant value is expected.

I thougth about creating an enum, but seems to be the wrong way, tryed something like :

```
public const int AppleId = new Fruits().ID_APPLE;
```

Not working either...
Someone have an idea?

Comment: `private int _ID_BANANA = (int)1;` is **not** constant. It's a private field that can be modified in class-scope. In given example property `_ID_BANANA` modifies it. The same about the second field.

Comment: C# coding convention should be followed

Comment: That class you showed surely won't compile. It defines `_ID_BANANA` and `_ID_APPLE` twice. Please show your real code.

Comment: @PLB It is mean to be a constant, nobody will change it. So if you want I would like an enum that is a "snapshot" of a new instance.

Comment: @Thomas How is compiler supposed to know that programmers will keep their word and won't touch those fields? :)

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth You are rigth, fixed

Comment: @PLB, I don't care if someone create an Fruits and change the values. The protocole is defined as : the default values are the good one, so I would like a snapshot of these default values in an enum or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use `if else if` statements here?

```
var fruits = new Fruits();
if (idFruit == fruits._ID_BANANA)
    return Color.Yellow;
else if (idFruit == fruits._ID_APPLE)
    return Color.Green;
else
    return Color.White;
```

Or dictionary:

```
this.fruitsColorMap = new Dictionary<int, Color>
    {
        { fruits._ID_BANANA, Color },
        { fruits._ID_APPLE, Green }
    };
```

And then:

```
public static Color GetColor(int idFruit) {
    if (this.fruitsColorMap.ContainsKey(idFruit) {
        return this.fruitsColorMap[idFruit];
    }
    return Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Because this would be sweeping the issue under the rug without having understood it first.

Comment: That's working for the mapping method, but I would like to use theses values as an enum or const for example in my unit tests.

Comment: @Thomas: Than make this property type as an `enum` and use this within your switch statement.

Comment: @Olivier, I cannot change the generated files.

Comment: @Sergey Metlov I would like to access in my code somehow to the name of the thing like : `(int)Myclass.Apple`.

Comment: I will go for the If else statement with `public static readonly int APPLE = new Fruits().ID_APPLE;`

Answer (score 0):

The case values in a switch statement have to be constants - that's part of the switch statement's definition:

```
switch (expression)
{
   case constant-expression:
      statement
      jump-statement
   [default:
       statement
       jump-statement]
 }
```

as per the [switch (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) documentation from Microsoft.

you will notice the `constant-expression` bit. That means that it can be determined at compile time. So calls to functions (and a reference to a property property is really a function call in disguise) are not allowed here.

Comment: You are true, I will use a if statement instead.